# Dart selecting random elements in a list but it should not select the element over 77

Tags: dart

I have a list of numbers 0 to 77 represents  Tarot cards and this list continues number from 77 to 155 represents reversed  types of this Tarot cards. I want to select randomly 10 of theese cards, if i select card number 0 i shoudnt select reversed type of it (number 78).

Deep explanation;

I have a 78 tarot cards. They have both straight and reversed meanings. They are all in a list of array 78+78 = 156 I want to choose 10 of them . For example the first card I choose is the array number 0. its reversed number is 78. for the second card i choose, souldn't choose the card number 78 because number 0 and the number 78 is the same card. The next card i choose  I hope I explained well.

My code is bellow but not work like i supoosed. Can you help me ? Thank you.

```dart
var list = [];

@override
void initState() {
  _advertService.showBanner();

  for (int i = 0; i < 155; i++) {
    list.add(i);
  }

  var Randomlist = (list.toList()..shuffle());
  print(Randomlist);

  firstCard = Randomlist[0];

  secondCard = Randomlist[1];
  thirdCard = Randomlist[2];
  fourthCard = Randomlist[3];
  fifthCard = Randomlist[4];
  sixthCard = Randomlist[5];
  seventhCard = Randomlist[6];
  eightethCard = Randomlist[7];
  ninethCard = Randomlist[8];
  tenthCard = Randomlist[9];
}
```

Comment: Can you give a few examples of how the algorithm should work? Also, you have shuffled the full list of Tarot cards in you code so I am a little confused by the concept of "reversed types" in the same list since everything is just random now.

Comment: @murat Did you mean `reserved` and misspelled it as `reversed`?

Comment: I have a 78 tarot cards. They have both straight and reversed meanings. They are all in a list of array 78+78 = 156   I want to choose 10 of them . For example the first card I choose is the array number 0. its reversed number is 78. for the second card i choos i soudnit choose the card number 78 because number 0 and the number 78 is the same card. I hope I explained well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined the first ten cards and their reversed types.
Then i choose a random card from list, then i deducted it and its reversed type.
Then i did it for the other cards. Now its working all good. I have posted this for who have the same problem

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 155; i++) {
    list.add(i);
  }

  firstCard = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)];
  if (firstCard < 78) {
    firstCard2 = 78 + firstCard;
    list.remove(firstCard);
    list.remove(firstCard2);
  } else {
    firstCard2 = firstCard - 78;
    list.remove(firstCard);
    list.remove(firstCard2);
  }

  secondCard = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)];
  if (secondCard < 78) {
    secondCard2 = 78 + secondCard;
    list.remove(secondCard);
    list.remove(secondCard2);
  } else {
    secondCard2 = secondCard - 78;
    list.remove(secondCard);
    list.remove(secondCard2);
  }

  thirdCard = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)];
  if (thirdCard < 78) {
    thirdCard2 = 78 + thirdCard;
    list.remove(thirdCard);
    list.remove(thirdCard2);
  } else {
    thirdCard2 = thirdCard - 78;
    list.remove(thirdCard);
    list.remove(thirdCard2);
  }

  fourthCard = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)];
  if (fourthCard < 78) {
    fourthCard2 = 78 + fourthCard;
    list.remove(fourthCard);
    list.remove(fourthCard2);
  } else {
    fourthCard2 = fourthCard - 78;
    list.remove(fourthCard);
    list.remove(fourthCard2);
  }
  fifthCard = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)];
  if (fifthCard < 78) {
    fifthCard2 = 78 + fifthCard;
    list.remove(fifthCard);
    list.remove(fifthCard2);
  } else {
    fifthCard2 = fifthCard - 78;
    list.remove(fifthCard);
    list.remove(fifthCard2);
  }

  sixthCard = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)];
  if (sixthCard < 78) {
    sixthCard2 = 78 + sixthCard;
    list.remove(sixthCard);
    list.remove(sixthCard2);
  } else {
    sixthCard2 = sixthCard - 78;
    list.remove(sixthCard);
    list.remove(sixthCard2);
  }

  seventhCard = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)];
  if (seventhCard < 78) {
    seventhCard2 = 78 + seventhCard;
    list.remove(seventhCard);
    list.remove(seventhCard2);
  } else {
    seventhCard2 = seventhCard - 78;
    list.remove(seventhCard);
    list.remove(seventhCard2);
  }

  eightethCard = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)];
  if (eightethCard < 78) {
    eightethCard2 = 78 + eightethCard;
    list.remove(eightethCard);
    list.remove(eightethCard2);
  } else {
    eightethCard2 = eightethCard - 78;
    list.remove(eightethCard);
    list.remove(eightethCard2);
  }

  ninethCard = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)];
  if (ninethCard < 78) {
    ninethCard2 = 78 + ninethCard;
    list.remove(ninethCard);
    list.remove(ninethCard2);
  } else {
    ninethCard2 = ninethCard - 78;
    list.remove(ninethCard);
    list.remove(ninethCard2);
  }

  tenthCard = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)];
  if (tenthCard < 78) {
    tenthCard2 = 78 + tenthCard;
    list.remove(tenthCard);
    list.remove(tenthCard2);
  } else {
    tenthCard2 = tenthCard - 78;
    list.remove(tenthCard);
    list.remove(tenthCard2);
  }
```